# Navigate to another page from radwindow

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

**Scenario:-**
I've a local asp.net website directory :- "`http://localhost/DemoWebsite/`". A "Secure" folder is inside it. Two webpages are inside that folder :- Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx. And one more webpage:- Page3.aspx is outside the folder.

**Requirement:-**
Now 'Page2.aspx' is opening in a RadWindow from the parent page 'Page1.aspx'. A button 'Cancel' is there in 'Page2.aspx' and on-click of that button I want to come out of RadWindow and directly move to 'Page3.aspx'.

**Attempted Solution:-**
Button's 'OnClientClick' event is set to a JS function 'LogOff()'.
Definition is:-

```
function LogOff()
{        
   top.location.href = "http://localhost/DemoWebsite/Page3.aspx";
}
```

The Problem is that since I can't give the above mentioned enitre link when I want this website to push in some other server. So if I give the link as:-

`top.location.href = "~/Page3.aspx";` OR Just, `top.location.href = "Page3.aspx";`

And when I run the website and click the Cancel Button. It throws error "Resource can't be found." It is because after button click it tries the link `"/DemoWebsite/Secure/Page3.aspx".`

**Question**:- what to assign for  `top.location.href`so that it tries the link `"/DemoWebsite/Page3.aspx"`. As Page3.aspx is **NOT** in Secure folder.

Comment: @ALL - As Chris' answer suggested, for my problem i need to use "../Page3.aspx". Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like.... `GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.location.href = '../page3.aspx';`

`GetRadWindow()` is a function that gets a reference to your radwindow....

```
function GetRadWindow()
{
var oWindow = null; if (window.radWindow)
    oWindow = window.radWindow; else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
    oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; return oWindow;
}
```

The `BrowserWindow` part will get a reference to your window that the radwindow opened from.  The rest just redirects the opening window to the location that you want.

**EDIT**:  after looking at your question again i think you just need to know how to get to the relative path through javascript?  if that is the case it is like this... `document.location.href = '../'; //Up one level`.   The ../ will jump you back one level.  If you just use /path then it will assume you are going from the same folder level that your current page is on.

Comment: No problem.  I know its tough to find good documentation sometimes for the Telerik controls.